# Cross Platform AES CryptLib

Tags: go, encryption

I am trying to convert the logic of [Crypt Lib in js](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/blob/master/Node/src/CryptLib.js) I have existing android application and the API is in c sharp and I want to convert encrypt and decrypt logic.

I have tried multiple variations you can check the code: [Tried code](https://play.golang.org/p/7ePy4wMd8f6)

I have a sample data which I want to decrypt and the data is:

```
{"Data":"bvtkHfZiTsY0CX6QmHhCboBwXeY9RZVPpdhhdIy6aSwCTVI7YiEGha1aXTIKY4BocGdNIbWkreQHZcTk4WE6F2tQLoVyWERYCGZotbDzxxs=","IV":"Vmr-uU5mA2_Zr_13"}
```

Here I have the encrypted data in Data and IV so when I am trying to decrypt this data I can't find any solution. All the encrypt and decrypt function is in csharp and android code. But I want to convert the same logic in golang.

The logic in [Node](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/blob/master/Node/src/CryptLib.js)

I have tried this code:

```
    iv := []byte("Vmr-uU5mA2_Zr_13")
    key := []byte("<Secret_Key")

    text := []byte("bvtkHfZiTsY0CX6QmHhCboBwXeY9RZVPpdhhdIy6aSwCTVI7YiEGha1aXTIKY4BocGdNIbWkreQHZcTk4WE6F2tQLoVyWERYCGZotbDzxxs=")

    cipherBlock, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(cipherBlock, iv).CryptBlocks(text, text)
    fmt.Println(string(text))
```

Full [link](https://play.golang.org/p/iI1emvcue0_z) to the code and I am getting error:

```
crypto/aes: invalid key size 64
```

Comment: The call to `base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString` is returning an error ("illegal base64 data at input byte 3")

Comment: Edited the question I am trying to replicate the same thing like node js exmple. And golang cipher I am using the code but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to decode your `key` and `text` strings properly into byte slices, not just cast them. The code below works, although I am not sure what the decoded message should look like...

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "encoding/base64"
    "crypto/cipher"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "crypto/aes"
)

func main() {
    iv := "Vmr-uU5mA2_Zr_13"
    key := "<Secret_Key>"
    ciphertext := "bvtkHfZiTsY0CX6QmHhCboBwXeY9RZVPpdhhdIy6aSwCTVI7YiEGha1aXTIKY4BocGdNIbWkreQHZcTk4WE6F2tQLoVyWERYCGZotbDzxxs="
    
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(key))
    key = hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])[:32]
    
    btext, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(ciphertext)
    if err != nil {
        println("Error decoding cipertext: ", err.Error())
        return
    }

    aesCipher, err := aes.NewCipher([]byte(key))
    if err != nil {
        println("Error creating cipher: ", err.Error())
        return
    }

    cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(aesCipher, []byte(iv)).
        CryptBlocks(btext, btext)
    
    println("Result: ", string(btext))
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nwoow/b417de31c725fa7ffcb3d63606ec7a3b here in this code I get the output you can see. This is a node js code which is using library https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/tree/master/Node I am getting exact output. I treid code above but I am unable to get right response.

Comment: In that example the key is hashed, let me update the solution

Comment: The key in that gist is different to the key in the question - and neither seem to give a plain text output - are you sure all the values are correct?

Comment: Okay, I got it, there is some funky manipulation of the key going on - will update

Comment: Can you explain this line: key = hex.EncodeToString(hash[:])[:32] and if I have to encrypt then which logic I should use. It would be great if you can answer that.

Comment: And I am getting the exact response with extra values \b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b like this when I am converting it to json reponse

Comment: Thats probably padding that has been added by the Node implementation.